# how to dynamically change active class in navbar using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the navbar to dynamically change class to 'active' in the current page when the user click on the `<li>` tag. Where did I go wrong?

```js
dynamicNavbar();

function dynamicNavbar() {
  $('.nav_w3ls .menu a').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav_w3ls .menu').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('a').addClass('active');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_w3ls ml-lg-5">
  <nav>
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="why_us.php">Why Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-right-sty mt-lg-0 mt-sm-4 mt-3">
        <a href="pages/login.php" class="reqe-button text-uppercase">Login</a>
        <a href="pages/register.php" class="reqe-button text-uppercase">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I expect the navbar to be active for the current page

Comment: When you click a link, your browser creates a new HTTP call and completely reloads the page. What you see afterwards is no longer the DOM in which you activated the JS `click` event

Comment: when you click on a link, a new page will load and therefore you will lose the active class, this either needs to be added through server side language or on load of the document

Comment: this codepen prevent from navigation, and set active class to clicked element. while it doesnt answer question completely, perhaps its good to check it : https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/oNvYpZB?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get you page name. Then you add the class to the `a` element that has this page name as `href` attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav_w3ls .menu').find('a.active').removeClass('active');

    var sPath = window.location.pathname;
    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    $('.nav_w3ls .menu').find('a[href=' + sPage + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active');

Comment: @Saeed, `this.location.pathname` will return the whole path, not only the page name. But he can use `$('a[href="' + sPage + '"]').addClass('active');`

Comment: thanks a lot @Danilo Korber. I use $('a[href="' + sPage + '"]').addClass('active'); it works perfectly

Comment: Glad I could help, @TobyNwude. The only problem with the solution `$('a[href="' + sPage + '"]').addClass('active');` is that the class will be added to **all** `a` elements with this `href`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
dynamicNavbar();

function dynamicNavbar() {
  $('.nav_w3ls .menu a').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav_w3ls .menu').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_w3ls ml-lg-5">
  <nav>
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="why_us.php">Why Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-right-sty mt-lg-0 mt-sm-4 mt-3">
        <a href="pages/login.php" class="reqe-button text-uppercase">Login</a>
        <a href="pages/register.php" class="reqe-button text-uppercase">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Your code worked just fine, the only issue was on the last line. You didn't have to call the "parent method" on the 'this'.
`$(this).addClass('active');`